# VB.NET compilation error when using nullable boolean? or date? as optional parameter

Tags: vb.net, nullable, optional-parameters

If I have a method that accepts Optional Nullable Dates or Booleans as such:

```
Public Function GetAll(Optional ByVal publishToDate As Date? = Nothing, _
                       Optional ByVal publishFromDate As Date? = Nothing, _
                       Optional ByVal isDisabled As Boolean? = Nothing) As DataTable
```

And I call this method without passing any parameters :

```
dt = GetAll()
```

I will get a compilation error when building :

- **Error  37  compilation failed : '0xC0000005'   vbc : Command line**

If i just use optional nullable integers, its fine. But will always raise an error when using Date or Boolean as Nullable Optional parameters. I do not want to overload because I want to use these parameters (and more) as conditions for an SQL WHERE clause.

The strange thing is, I have tested the above in a separate console application and it works fine.

Note - Currently this method resides in its own assembly that is referenced by a website. IDE is VS 2010. Framework 3.5.

Any ideas for a successful build?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Nullable(Of Date)` and `Nullable(Of Boolean)` instead of `Date?` and `Boolean?`

Comment: It is not a compilation error, your code crashed the compiler.  A hard crash too, nothing you could easily fix.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com, meanwhile you'll have to think of another way to do this to avoid this crash.

Comment: @PinnyM tried those too - same result.

Comment: What happens if you provide a value for the optional parameters? E.g. `dt = GetAll(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)` ?

Comment: @HansPassant - alright will have to report this then. Thanks anyways. Looks like im gonna have to find another way.

Comment: @Origin - If I pass in Nothing for all the parameters, it works fine. But I want this method to be used without passing anything for all parameters.

Comment: I know it's a dirty workaround, but why not overload a method like so:

    Public Function GetAll() as DataTable
        return GetAll(Nothing,Nothing,Nothing)
    End Function

Comment: Sorry it will not work as well, passing in Nothing. If it is NOT an Optional parameter and passing in Nothing, then it will work; but it will not work when its Optional and Nullable.

Comment: @Origin - But I will have to work with methods like GetAll(fromDate, toDate) and GetAll(isDisabled) and GetAll(fromDate, toDate, isDisabled) .. so that'll be alot of overlaoding.

Comment: Well, I guess your two options are to overload, or make it required. I think making it required (but nullable) would be less work, even though it would result in some unsightly function calls with a few "Nothing" values.

Comment: @Origin - Yup, had to resort to passing in Nothings as inputs.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2018. If I run vbc from the command line, on a website project, with the `-errorstack` option I get the error `[HttpCompileException]: vbc : Command line (0): error BC2010: compilation failed : '0xC0000005' at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()`